# how to use {{}} inside of asset helper laravel

Tags: laravel, image, assets

I have a dynamic image that a user can change, so I need to grab the path from the database. Everything works fine if I do:

```
<img src="/storage/{{ $client->image->path }}">
```

But this doesn't work:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/{{ $client->image->path }}') }}">
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already opened the curly braces once. You can process it in accordance with the syntax. Try like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/' . $client->image->path) }}">
```